# How to resize vertical split with mouse when using telephone-line instead of mode-line?

Tags: mode-line, window-splitting, mouse

According to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9646770), one can resize a vertical split with the mouse by dragging the mode-line in a specific spot.

I'm using telephone-line and can't find any spot on there to resize the vertical splits. Dragging the telephone-line itself only resizes horizontal splits.

How can I resize vertical splits with my mouse when not using the default mode-line?

[image: Screenshot of my Emacs setup]

Comment: We've found the terms "vertical" and "horizontal" to be ambiguous when describing splits (does "vertical" refer to the fact that the new windows are arranged vertically, or that the dividing line between them is vertical?), so we prefer to describe them as "above/below" vs "left/right".

Comment: Makes sense. I used this terminology because of evil-modes horizontal and vertical split. In this case I'm talking about how to resize windows in a left/right split, if this makes any more sense. Not really sure how to reword the question with a above/below/left/right terminology.

Comment: The spot to use (with the default mode-line) is pretty darn small (and AFAIK it's independent from the actual mode-line): have you managed to use it?  If not then I suspect your problem has nothing to do with the telephone-line.

Comment: You're right, no wonder I didn't find it before! I added an answer to the question, but feel free to add your own, so I can accept yours. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh wow, [Stefan](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/1979/stefan) was right - the spot to resize the windows with the mouse is *really* pretty darn small. I did find it after a while – I didn't realize that one doesn't have to click the middle of the windows, but actually a little bit further to the left. Hard to describe, so here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot showing the draggable location on the telephone-line]